# Compiling in Java 7 a method that uses Java 8 types

Tags: java, cross-compiling

I need to write code to handle dates. We are slowly transitioning from Java 7 to Java 8, so my library code **has to work** with both. For this reason it must be compiled Java 7.

However, projects already migrated to Java 8 started using JSR-310 types.

Consider the following statements

```
if (obj instanceof Date){
    //Serialize using SimpleDateFormat
} else if (obj instanceof org.joda.time.LocalDateTime){
    //Serialize using Joda
} else if (obj instanceof java.time.LocalDateTime){
    //Serialize using JSR 310
}
```

I am not using Lambdas or other language stuff introduced by Java 8. I am using a Java 8 compiler anyway. What I want is to create Java 7 compatible code (so no `UnsupportedClassVersionError`) that breaks when the third if branch is hit in Java 7 (`NoClassDefFoundError`).

Currently the above code does not compile at all if I use a Java 8 javac compiler set for Java 7 target.

I run Ant in a Java 8 environment

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src" destdir="build/compiled" target="1.7" source="1.7"
```

But if I use `import java.time.LocalDateTime` as a *trick* it won't compile.
I imagined that a Java 8 compiler targeting to Java 7 was not so smart to see that while the `LocalDateTime` class **is available** in Java 8 classpath, it is not in Java 7.

What I don't want is to use reflection (`if (obj.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("java.time.LocalDateTime")` and other reflection-based stuff) and I prefer not to add a dependency to [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.threeten/threetenbp) as JSR-310 types are **not** being used in Java 7 projects and I prefer to exclude threeten from Java 8 projects without messing with the Ivy dependencies file.

Any smart idea? I already have a solution (Service Provider Interface with separate Jars) but I want to keep it as last resort.

Comment: Check whether the old software (easily) runs under java 8, and do a runtime transition first. Anything else is messy. Then you can migrate at leisure, with correct feedback.

Comment: Some customers are not migrating to Java 8 until 2025. That is my constraint

Comment: Given that the compiler will always include a reference to `java.time` your attempt to write a J7 and J8 compatible solution won't work. Stick to jodatime if you cannot migrate to J8 at this time (though J7 was from '11, and J8 from '14).

Comment: "Some customers are not migrating to Java 8 until 2025" Then you're stuck with Java 7 until 2025. But, seriously... zoiks. You know that we'll be several more versions of Java down the line by then?

Comment: Comment: 2025 is an optimistic estimation. When I asked my consultants "when are they expecting to migrate?" answer was one word: **never**

Comment: Then you're stuck with Java 7 forever.

Comment: Likely. But as I said in the question some projects using my library code are already using Java 8 and JSR 310.

Comment: You could create an external project with a stub java.time.LocalDateTime class, compile the jar, and put it in classpath *after* the jvm so it favors loading the java virtual machine version first.  This would work using your example, but if you think this is a bad solution, it's worse.  It is a terrible idea for a number of reasons, but at least it gets the job done.  I think it is a better solution to assume there will be no java.time.LocalDateTime until you can know you can dedicate to java 8.

Comment: **Branch.** You will never get happy with the current constellation: under java 8 not using all those new things (lambdas, but still LocalDateTime); it is more like switching from C to C++ but resting compatible with C. You can drop joda in the 8er version, use lambdas, streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sure way of making your code Java7 AND Java8-compatible is to not use any Java8-specific features, including any classes introduced in Java8 and bytecode versions. The standard engineering practice is to follow the greatest-common-factor principle, which is Java7 and Java7-compatible libraries.

The import trick won't save you anything. JVM will load the class sooner or later, and then you'll either get one exception or another.

Using reflection would work, but you'd end up with horribly ugly and unreadable code with no type safety. On top of it, making your code run differently on different JVM versions can be a pain to debug.

There are other underhanded tricks such as manipulating bytecode or class loading, but this is thin ice and might break when you least need it.

If you absolutely have to use different versions side-by-side, you could separate the code into two parts and run it in separate JVMs. But if you're only writing a library, it's probably easier to make two versions - one for Java7 (also compatible with Java8) and one for Java8.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a solution on the wrong "level". You want to avoid code duplication, and thus you are looking for a *technical* solution to something I would rather call a "meta versioning" problem.

Thus a dedicated none-answer: consider dropping the idea of having single code base that serves **two** masters. Instead: "branch off" a java7 version of your library. Your "master" branch on the other hand fully supports java8. Of course, the java7 version only exists for important bug fixes, that must go into it - all active development happens on your "master" java8 branch. And then use technology to support you - for example things like [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to reduce efforts when you have to make similar updates in both branches.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do : **Branch the code**. The master would be Java 8 version.

A less recommended approach: Use your build framework to decide the date handler.
 You can have 2 submodules. The submodules can have a class in same package. And the call to the class would be:

```
MyDateHandler.handle();
```

And your build file decides which class to take based on the java version.
In maven we can have profiles. So in one profile you can build with Java 7 implementation of MyDateHandler. And in Java 8, you can build with Java 8 implementation.

Comment: This is actually what we are doing at the moment: two modules in two separate artifacts